# Form submission using $_SESSION data - more secure/correct method?

Tags: php, security

I currently have a form that has a hidden form field, populated based on a variable in the user's session.  A function is called when this form is submitted, which processes the form, and this hidden variable is pretty important to it.

Is it better to do things like this, or to just call the session variable directly in the function (so pull the variable from the session of the person who called the function - aka submitted the form)?  Or, is this exactly the same...?

I'm trying to think in terms of application security here.

Thanks

Comment: use the session variable directly is 'safer

Comment: That way you don't expose it to the user though the hidden form field.

Comment: @Sander - hmmm gotcha.   Can't a user see his session variables if he wants to?  Or are these always impossible to get as a user?

Comment: @Shackrock - A user can't see the session variables unless you have a page that is just displaying them.  That is the whole point of them being stored server side.  There is a cookie (PHPSESSID by default) that stores a unique value which maps to the server side information which php loads automatically when session_start() is issued retrieving any of the information currently stored in the session.

Comment: @judda - awesome, I had thought that at one point, makes perfect sense.  So... why do I hear that some people encrypt stored SESSION variables?  If it's server side only, I don't see the point.

Comment: By default, session data is stored on disk.  If you're on shared hosting and the server is not properly configured, you could possibly read session files that you don't own.  The set of people that store data in sessions that needs to be encrypted and the set of people that use shared hosting should not intersect by policy, but sometimes people don't always make the best hosting choice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session variables are stored server side so the server would have to be told to give them out.  As long as you aren't requesting that information, it is safe on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the session variable directly because it limits the possibility for an attacker to modify the variable.   **Unless** of course this is a CSRF token.  Its common to store a random value as a `$_SESSION` variable and then comparing it with a hidden form field.